# SQL Server : Table valued function returning dates for last 10 days from today

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am new to SQL Server and am trying to write a table valued function that returns dates for the last 10 days from the current date. How do I do this?

Comment: Start by referring to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Create a function (with help from the documentation as suggested above) and then start writing your code. If you get stuck, then show us that code and where you are stuck. Also show us sample data and expected outcome, as text NOT as image

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will take you a step closer. You can use below code to get last 10 dates + today.
Tweak this and push this into a function.

```
SELECT 
    date = DATEADD(d,-1* days,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
FROM
    (
    VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    )V(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a procedure that finds the last 10 days for a given input date like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getLast10Days(@inputDate DATETIME)
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count = 1;
WHILE @count <= 10
BEGIN
PRINT DATEADD(DAY, - @count, @inputDate)
SET @count = @count + 1
END
END
GO
```

In order to execute this procedure for the current date, this will do:

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME
SET @currentDate = GETDATE()
EXEC dbo.getLast10Days @inputDate = @currentDate
```

If you don't want to use the current date as getdate(), but to use a date from a table, just do something like this:

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME
SET @currentDate = SELECT theDateColumn FROM yourTable
EXEC dbo.getLast10Days @inputDate = @currentDate
```